# Buying a used hard disk with Interface CRC errors

Tags: hard-drive, smart, crc

A guy on a forum has listed his 6TB Western Digital Red hard drive for sale. He has sold several products before and has a good track record so he is not a scammer.

He has posted the following screenshot containing SMART info. He says the Interface CRC errors are due to a faulty SATA cable he used for a few months.

[image: SMART]

Is it safe to use this hard drive on a desktop? I would be using it to store my steam library and movie collection.

Comment: A better question to ask yourself might be "What happens when this component fails?"  Every component of a PC can fail, potentially resulting in data loss.  If this is the only copy of the data, then it is lost. If there is only a year-old copy and you've made important changes since then, then you've lost part of it.  Consider what data to back up, when, and what methods to use.  Component failure always happens eventually, and it's never convenient.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a used hard drive will have higher chance of failure and sooner time of failure than a new hard drive, due to the bathtub curve.  Some devices have problems that passed initial QA, leading to high failure rates in the first few months, then there are several years of normal operations with low failure rates, then a rising rate of failure as the parts wear out.  A used hard drive is somewhere in the middle, and also has suffered the rigors of transport multiple times.

Google did a white paper on hard drive failure modes and rates about a decade ago. I don't see a specific mention of Interface CRC errors, so it's possible that they screened out faulty connector cables before adding them to the study.
https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf

BackBlaze did an analysis of their hard drives, including correlating various SMART errors with full failures of the disk.  Again, I don't see a specific mention of Interface CRC errors.  https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/